# Google chrome did not shutdown correctly

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, kde-4

I get the "Google chrome did not shutdown correctly" message every time I reboot my computer. I'm using:

- Google chromium 8.0.552
- KDE 4.5.4

I believe this has something to do with chrome not obeying the shutdown signal which KDE sends to all applications on quit. So then KDE kills chromium and then the message has to appear. Does anyone know how to stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are not actually closing the browser before you reboot. Whenever the browser is forcibly killed by the kernel or KDE, it will display that message to try and make it easy for you to reopen lost tabs. In the future, just close Chromium first, then reboot.

Comment: KDE is sending force-quit signal when application does not respond to normal termination request. Other applications does not have this problem. They obey and quit. Although this is not a solution I've been looking for, I think it should be accepted as it's best known workaround.